# How to get an array of strings instead of object from with() function?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

This is the Laravel ProductController and Products has a many-to-many relationship with Tags.

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::with('tags')->latest()->get();
    return response()->json($products);
}
```

On the json response, if I map the products, **product.tag** is returning an array of objects.

```
[{"name": "shirt"}, {"name": "red"}]
```

Is there a way to get only the name property at the **with('tags')** at the controller, like:

```
["shirt", "red"]
```

Also I have been trying something like this:

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::with(['tags' => function ($query) {
        $result = $query->select(['name']);
        return $result->get();
    }])->latest()->get();
    return response()->json($products);
}
```

Its possible to filter the data inside tags function?

Comment: use `pluck` function of Laravel to get array.

Comment: you are asking for a solution in your ajax call, so why don't you can loop product.tag for your purpose in js.

Comment: Sure, it works! But i wanted the data to come ready to use from the api.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a Resource class to return just the items required in your API. This includes being able to process child relationships.  See https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources#generating-resources

Or, you can do it the way you tried with `select` but more like;

```
    $products = Product::with(['tags' => function ($query) {
        return $query->select(['name']);
    }])->latest()->get();
```